# Passing a component as props for another component in Routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have components like `Dashboard`, `Users`, `Posts`, `Category` and so on and I want to render these components inside `Admin` component. when my Url will be : `/admin/dashboard` I want to render `Dashboard` inside `Admin` , when my url will be : `/admin/users` I want to render `Users` inside `Admin` and so on.
For this my Routing is:

```
            <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
            <Route exact path='/admin/dashboard'
                component={() => <Admin comp={<Dashboard />} />}
            />
            <Route exact path='/admin/users
                component={() => <Admin comp={<Users />} />}
            />
            <Route exact path='/admin/posts'
                component={() => <Admin comp={<Post />} />}
            />
            <Route exact path='/admin/category'
                component={() => <Admin comp={<Category />} />}
            />
```

My question is: Is this good approach of routing?

Answer (score 0):

You already know which component should be displayed for a route. Then why do you want to use a parent component named Admin, instead you can directly render the exact component which is need to be rendered.